# Low throughput of spray application

Tags: performance, scala, jvm, akka, spray

I am working on spray application that is expected to work as a part of real time bidder so both latency and throughput are very important (~80 ms - maximal latency, N*10000 rps are required). But now I experience a very low throughput (less than 1000 rps) on AWS machine of c4.2xlarge type (8 cores CPU, 16GB memory,  ulimit - 500000). As I can see from jvm and system monitoring, it is far from being limited by CPU, memory, disk IO or networking.

The system contains mainly two pools of actors on request critical path and I don't see that throughput is increased when I increase pools (when pools are increased, I mostly see increased latency). So I think the problem can be in context switching. So I'd be glad to see advises regarding actor dispatchers configuration.

Some more details about the application architecture.

The system contains two sets of actors on request critical path: pool of ServerActor (extends spray HttpService) and pool of BiddingAgentActor. ServerActor just sends message with ask pattern (route is handled with its future) to BidderAgentActor. BidderAgentActor handles request mostly synchronously.  It uses Futures for work concurrently when possible, but waits for result of final future. No external calls are made in this process (no DB queries, no HTTP calls...). There are several more actors in the application and BiddingAgentActor sends to them messages for offline processing.

**Updated**

Here is a link to a bit simplified code for both BidderAgentActor pool and for BidderAgentActor created per request: [gist](https://gist.github.com/olga-gorun/f115e784bac316d81e35ba31a22d40d3)

Versions:
scala - 2.11.8
akka - 2.3.12
spray - 1.3.1
OS: ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Do you have different dispatchers configure for the different pool of actors? If you are sharing the same dispatcher it could be that the ServerActor is just waiting for threads to be released.

Comment: I use default akka settings for akka dispatchers. For Futures I use scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global executor. Do you suggest to use separate dispatcher configuration per actor type? I'll try this.

Comment: Is there anything blocking in the code such as 'Await.result`?

Comment: @hveiga, I used different pools (2 separate fork join dispatchers for ServiceActor pool and for BidderAgentActor pool) but didn't see any difference.

Comment: @MustafaSimav Yes, as I said in initial post BiddingAgentActor waits for result of final future (uses Await.result). ServerActor doesn't. It completes route with ask pattern future. But the problem is that increasing of BiddingAgentActor pool doesn't increase throughput.

Comment: Can you add the code for your spray route?

Comment: @OlgaGorun blocking actors isn't a good idea and it is highly discouraged. I recommend you to take a look at actor per request model http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2013/12/ask-tell-and-per-request-actors/

I believe it is because of blocking threads but It's hard to see the problem without profiling.

Comment: @MustafaSimav, thank you for response. Fixed pool of blocking actors was my attempt to be sure that I won't get to exposure of memory. I have also branch where BidderAgentActor is created per request and, generally speaking, don't see better performance there. But I understand that it is difficult to advice without profiling when there are too many variables. So I try to reduce question to a case of configured pool. If it is threads blocking, why I don't see improvement when actors pool is increased?

Comment: There could be other bottlenecks, too. For example, blocking on ServerActor also decrease performance. Or somehow ServerActor and BidderAgentActor might be sharing same thread pool. Or global execution context might have exhausted. As I said, it is hard to guess.

Comment: @OlgaGorun I would suggest attaching code of actors to the question.

Comment: @OlgaGorun from the attached code it is not clear what is actually happening in onBidRequest, code is not complete. Anyway I would suggest using http://kamon.io/  to understand what's going on in your actor system - how fast messages are sent out, what is average time in receive method etc. Also use standard JVM tools to see how threads used.